# Firebase Phone Authentication on Flutter IOS is identified as Unknown Origin Requests

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-app-check

I am using flutter with Firebase and facing a problem with App Check only on IOS.

I've uploaded my .p8 device check key to my firebase project and wrote its name and the app is registered successfully.

I've configured as per documentation as below:

```
await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
    webRecaptchaSiteKey: 'recaptcha-v3-site-key',
  );
```

**Results are very strange:**

The app check metrics shows my requests to Firestore as **Verified Requests.**
however, it shows my requests to Authentication as **Unverified: Unknown Origin Requests**.

I am wondering how the app check is working OK for Firestore but not for Authentication.

I am using a real iPhone7 device with IOS15 and I am running a release build on the iPhone by command:

**- flutter run --release**

Any advice where is the problem?

BR,
Sherif Said Elahl